# how do I enable gnome 3 on ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: gnome, vmware

It's been like 10 hours since I got down to Ubuntu so you could just say, I'm a perfect noob for the time being.

Thing is, I installed or better, tried to install Gnome-3 by dropping 3 commands which are apparently everywhere and look like:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

now that far, things were all-ok until I restarted and tried to actually enable gnome. the only way for doing that, which I've stumbled on is by tapping the tiny icon next to the password box, and supposedly it was to give me "gnome3" or something to go ahead with but there's nothing of that sort at all. I input my password, I click on the said icon and nothing. I'm logged in back to unity as alive and boring as ever. so looking forward for anyone to bestow their wisdom upon me. thanks in advance!

P.S : I'm running ubuntu on Vmware 10.0.1. Host OS is windows 7

Comment: try "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and type this following commands to install gnome 3

1) `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next`

2) `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging`

3) `sudo apt-get update`

4) `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

5) `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`

6) `sudo apt-get install gnome-weather gnome-music gnome-maps gnome-documents gnome-boxes gnome-shell-extensions gnome-tweak-tool gnome-clocks`

And simply restart your system

`sudo reboot`

Once we restarted the system, choose gnome as desktop environment and login to your account

Comment: i know I'm way too late, but thanks. it really works!